# Flutter: Disable picking the day from datePicker

Tags: flutter, datepicker, monthcalendar, flutter-cupertino, flutter-material

I'm trying to create a **month/year picker** in the Flutter project for both material and Cupertino styles. However, I can't find an ability to **disable the** **days** on the default date picker and the available packages only offer Cupertino-styled month pickers.

Did anyone face this kind of problem, and what was the most optimal solution? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use https://pub.dev/packages/month_year_picker ?

Comment: Yes, that one has a UI issue (opened on GitHub) and doesn't offer a solution for a cupertino-styled one.

Comment: i think it's easy to build just month and year selector :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `selectableDayPredicate` to control which `DateTime` should be enabled or disabled with a `bool` condition in your date picker :

```
      showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialDate: DateTime.now(),
              firstDate: DateTime(2022, 12, 10),
              lastDate: DateTime(2022, 12, 30),
              selectableDayPredicate: (date) {
                return date.day != 27;
              },
            )
```

In this example, the date picker will enable all days between the 10 and 30 of this month except the day 27, it will be disabled, preview :

[image: prove of disabling a specific day]

you can expand with your personal logic into this.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I don't need to show the dates at all and the user should only be able to select a month and a year from the picker.